# ADSL Line rate detected vs download speed

Tags: adsl

My modem detects the line rate as 8mbps, but in reality when I use speedtest.net I'm only downloading 7mbps max.

Is there a way I can configure my modem to get this extra 1mbps down?

Comment: What speed are you paying for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line can physically handle that top rate, but your actual rate is going to depend on the quality of and traffic on all the lines between you and the site you're connecting to.
Achieving the full rate will be a rare occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

The speed test generally measures the *useable* data rate that can be transferred over the line, but does not take into account TCP/IP headers, nor the error correction codes added by the ADSL itself.